# Munkres E.AT 44.2 Without Universal coefficient Thm, show if chain map is isomorphic on homology, is isomorphic on cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

**Edit:**Posting this question and proceeding on chapter 6, I found the solution in the next unit, unit45. So this question is practically solved, without universal coefficient theorem.

But as far as I remember through chapter 6 he did not mentions that he will prove such result on same chapter, unit 45.

I want to ask, What was his intention?

Original Question:

I am having trouble with understanding statement in Theorem 44.2 of Munkres, Elements of Algebraic Topology. I guess this is due to skipping and not thoroughly reading the whole book. It’s my fault, but I’am in a hurry in reading cohomology part of E.AT.

Thus this question is about specific book, Munkres, Elements of Algebraic topology, **I may need an answer respect to Munkres**. (Though I am not sure I can ask this kind of question.)

We are proving isomorphism between simplicial and singular cohomology. From unit 34, we’ve done isomorphism for homology by chain map
$$\eta:\mathcal{C}(K) \to \mathcal{S}(|K|)$$
which induces isomorphism in homology.On Theorem 44.2 he shows same result holds for cohomology: that induced cohomology-homomorphism  $\eta^{*}$ is cohomology isomorphism.

But in his proof he argues that:

> ”Because the chain complexes involved are free and $\eta$ induces a homology isomorphism, it induces a cohomology isomorphism as well.”

But why?

For universal coefficient theorem is on chpater 7(we are on chapter 5), about 70pages away, he is not using universal coefficient theorem.

I suspect there are two cases:

1. If this is literally correct, there is elementary solution without universal coefficient Thm or reason for his statement is trivial enough.
2. This is due to our specific chain map $\eta$ defined in unit 34.

For second case, I looked up a bit on unit 34 and checked that one of chain map in composition of $\eta$  is chain equivalence. But the other map is shown isomorphic, and I’m afraid that I need to keep on reading of cohomology part so I can’t read through proof and see if it does make cohomology homomorphism a isomorphism.

**Again I must repeat that this is about specific book, and why author has such reasoning, thus reason apart from text that is not elementary enough might not help.**(since we already have universal coefficient theorem)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is solved, you should delete the question.